# Updating a dynamically allocated fragment within a container using FragmentTransaction issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a Multipane app, where the left most pane is static and the right pane has dynamically added fragments.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:name="path.fragments.NavigationFragment"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_fragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/navigation_layout" />

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Whenever a list item is selected in the left pane, that contains the list of the users, I want to create a new fragment and add it to the container, and fill it with the messages from that user. The rest of my logic works great, but I am just having issues with the dynamically adding new fragments. updating the existing fragment before replacing it using the FragmentTransaction works. However, when I try the code below it doesn't work

```
    DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DetailsFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
    detailsFragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
    trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, detailsFragment);
    trans.addToBackStack(null);
    trans.commit();


    Log.v(TAG, "updating details fragment with argument = " + position);

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
    Peer peer = new Peer(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] {MessageContract.TEXT};
    int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
    adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            null,
            from,
            to, 2);

    detailsFragment = (DetailsFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    ListView LV = (ListView) detailsFragment.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    LV.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

In summary, what I am trying to do is:

- Create a new fragment
- add it to the container
- and update the view from the MainActivity

Additionally, inside the onCreate in the MainActivity I have this:

```
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        DetailsFragment firstFragment = new DetailsFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
```

Please accept my apologies if I am not clear enough, and thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Fragments Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

*"Calling commit() does not perform the transaction immediately. Rather, it schedules it to run on the activity's UI thread (the "main" thread) as soon as the thread is able to do so."*

You have the following lines of code almost immediately after committing the FragmentTransaction.

```
ListView LV = (ListView) detailsFragment.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
LV.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

It is most likely that the `View` for the `detailsFragment` has not been created yet.
Take a look at the [Complete Activity/Fragment Lifecycle](http://staticfree.info/~steve/complete_android_fragment_lifecycle.png). View creation does not occur until after the `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity`.

If you need to pass `adapter2` from the `Activity` to the `Fragment`, you could create a member variable and setter in your `Fragment`, but don't set the adapter on the `ListView` until the `Fragment's` `View` has been created.

For example, in your `Fragment`:

```
// member variable to hold the adapter
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter2;

// setter for the member variable
private void setAdapter2(SimpleCursorAdapter adapter) {
    mAdapter2 = adapter;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Now that the view is created, we can set the adapter.
    ListView LV = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    LV.setAdapter(mAdapter2);
}
```

And in your `Activity`:

```
// Create the new Fragment
DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();

// Add the Arguments to the Fragment
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(DetailsFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
detailsFragment.setArguments(args);

// Create the adapter
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
Peer peer = new Peer(cursor);

String[] from = new String[] {MessageContract.TEXT};
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
        null,
        from,
        to, 2);

// Set the Adapter for the Fragment
detailsFragment.setAdapter2(adapter2);

// Do the FragmentTransaction
FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, detailsFragment);
trans.addToBackStack(null);
trans.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware that commit was scheduled on the UI thread, instead of being executed immediately.